# Npm installing yo failing

Tags: node.js, npm, yeoman

I have a problem with **npm install -g yo**. It is giving me this error:

```
module.js:338
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module './cache/caching-client.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:22:24
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:466:3)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
```

I read somewhere that it might be because the NODE_PATH is incorrect so I ran this command in my terminal: "**echo $NODE_PATH**" and first I got the answer that my NODE_PATH was empty so I updated it to **/usr/local/lib/node_modules/**

Still running the command **npm install -g yo** fails.
Has anyone got any clue what the problem might be?

Comment: Did you try reinstalling node?

Comment: I am doing this right now as we are speaking

Comment: That solved the problem for me :)

Comment: Glad to hear that :)